# Why does SetWinEventHook sometimes stop/pause monitoring events?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, msaa

Starting up a WinEventHook doesn't seem to be working reliably.
What would cause an event hook to only monitor events (or run the identified event proc function) sometimes?

ie.  inside an IE8 BHO

```
HWINEVENTHOOK eHook = ::SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW, EVENT_OBJECT_REORDER
 , 0
 , MSAALib_WinEventProc
 , GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentThreadId()
 , WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT );
```

I've been getting events quite regularly, but after a recent build it doesn't work except when I'm also running MS "Accessible event watcher", stopping and starting the event watcher also stops and starts my event proc being called.

I haven't changed the SetWinEventHook in any recent build so I do not believe this is the cause.
All the other thread/message pumping actions are taking place as expected so I do not believe failure to pump messages on the thread is the cause.

Testing getting reorder events using http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/DOMtree.html and adding/removing test elements.

**Edit:**
Upon further testing it appears the change may have been that I stopped running the ["Accessible event watcher"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317979%28VS.85%29.aspx) and not the build.

The range of events captured by the event hook without the "Accessible event watcher" appears to be [first, last) or eventMin to eventMax-1 which is not as per the doc [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640%28VS.85%29.aspx) when starting the "Accessible event watcher" the range changes and appears to be [first,last] so using an eventMax of EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS seems to get the desired result of seeing EVENT_OBJECT_REORDER.

Is there something I'm missing here, or is the doc just wrong and the event watcher is doing something aswell?